# IE7/IE8 Table Display bug <thead> background image goes behind <table> background image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have been developing a new page which includes a series of tables.

The tables have a background image repeating on the y axis for the `<table>`. A background image for the `<thead>` and a background image for the `<tfoot>`

It works fine in all browsers except IE7 + IE8 - I have isolated the problem as: the repeating background image for the `<table>` is going above both the `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` - does anyone know how to fix this?

Any ideas welcome

Comment: I did a quick test in IE and it works fine. Do you have any IE specific styles or stylesheets on your page? It would be great if you posted your code.

Comment: Ditto Gert G. Simple test works fine in IE7.

Comment: Could you post your code, it would be much easier to debug. Cheers